# Map.delete() not working on key in parent Map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, key

What I'm doing right now, is deleting any diff that doesn't contain the string, and if the diff's dictionary is empty, then i try to delete the map.
the issue here is that, i can't delete a map with `data.delete(map)` for some reasons (no errors in console) and any piece of code located after that deletion in the if statement won't run.

here is the code in question:

```js
var data = new Map({"593620 Linked Horizon - Shinzou o Sasageyo! [TV Size]": {"difficulties": {"Titan": 86813}}, "859608 LiSA - ADAMAS (TV Size)": {"difficulties": {"Kibbleru's Blue Rose": 899}},"940746 CHiCO with HoneyWorks - Kimi ga Sora Koso Kanashikere": {"difficulties": {"Taeyang's Extra": 72321}}});
var string = "titan";

Array.from(data.keys()).forEach(function(map) {
        if (!(map.toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) >=0)) {
            if (document.getElementById("diff_search_box").checked) {
                Array.from(data.get(map).get("difficulties").keys()).forEach(function(diff) {
                    if (!(diff.toLowerCase().indexOf(string) >= 0)) {
                       data.get(map).get("difficulties").delete(diff)
                    }
                })
                if (Array.from(data.get(map).get("difficulties").keys()).length = 0) {
                    data.delete(map)
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

in this situation, I'm supposed to get a dictionary such as:

```json
{
    "593620 Linked Horizon - Shinzou o Sasageyo! [TV Size]": {
                                                                 "difficulties": {"Titan": 86813}
                                                             }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

surprising to see none of the previous answer saw that, another person on a discord server i do support for software stuff on pointed out the last if condition and the fact it's missing a `=` so it appear as

```js
if (Array.from(data.get(map).get("difficulties").keys()).length == 0) { 
// was = before, == now
    data.delete(map)
}
```

so now i indeed obtain a data dictionary with only 1 element containing the map which also have the difficulty that's contained in the specified string.

Answer (score 0):

Map needs an iterable like an array passed to it such as:

```
new Map([['Key 1', 'Value 1'], ['Key 1', 'Value 1']])
```

You can't pass an object literal to it but you can easily use `Object.entries()` to extract the needed array from your object.

Then you can use `Map.prototype.forEach()` to loop over all the Map entries

```js
var data = {"593620 Linked Horizon - Shinzou o Sasageyo! [TV Size]": {"difficulties": {"Titan": 86813}}, "859608 LiSA - ADAMAS (TV Size)": {"difficulties": {"Kibbleru's Blue Rose": 899}},"940746 CHiCO with HoneyWorks - Kimi ga Sora Koso Kanashikere": {"difficulties": {"Taeyang's Extra": 72321}}};

const map = new Map(Object.entries(data));

map.forEach((value, key) =>{
    const {difficulties}  = value;
    console.log('Map key:', key.toLowerCase());
    // if(someCondition){
    //     map.delete(key)
    // }
    Object.entries(difficulties).forEach(([k,v])=>{
        console.log('Diff key:', k, ' Diff value:', v)
        // if(k.toLowerCase().includes('titan')){
        //    delete difficulties[key];
        // }            
    })
    console.log('*****************************')       
})
```

Comment: this doesn't work since key doesn't return the string for me meaning i can't use key.toLowerCase()

Comment: I just changed the console to log `key.toLowerCase()` and it works fine. Pay attention to comment in @Isaac answer that you have a 'Huge number of problems" in your code

Comment: commented on all the issues in his answer

Comment: Sorry for trying to help. What is shown in question throws an error just creating the Map. Inside the loops there are numerous misconceptions also

Comment: you can thanks that rule, i also tried making an example that worked 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , will try fixing it, but not guaranteed to make it work as i did in my code without bloating it

Answer (score 0):

Huge number of problems with this code. My recommendation is don't write so much code without running it to make sure it works first. Write small pieces at a time and run it as you go making sure everything works along the way.

Issue number one is you cannot initialize a map with an object like that. The Map must be initialized with an array of arrays that are each two elements long, each containing the key value pairs for the map. You can fix this by wrapping the object in `Object.entries()` as that will return the key vale pairs for the object.

Second problem is `titan` is a string so it should be `"titan"`.

Number three, you're calling `.get` on an object in the line `data.get(map).get("difficulties")`. Objects do not have `.get`, you have to use brackets or dot syntax: `data.get(map).difficulties` or `data.get(map).difficulties`.

Fourth, I think you don't actually want to delete the data from the map. If you did, when the user changes the search text the old data would still be gone.

Why are you using map anyways? you can simply use a normal object.

Just do this if you must use maps:

```js
var data = new Map(Object.entries({
    "593620 Linked Horizon - Shinzou o Sasageyo! [TV Size]": {
        "difficulties": {"Titan": 86813}
    }, 
    "859608 LiSA - ADAMAS (TV Size)": {
        "difficulties": {"Kibbleru's Blue Rose": 899}
    },
    "940746 CHiCO with HoneyWorks - Kimi ga Sora Koso Kanashikere": {
        "difficulties": {"Taeyang's Extra": 72321}
    }
}));
var string = 'titan';

function search(s) {
    var r = {};
    for( const [key, value] of data ) {
        for( const diffKey in value.difficulties ) {
            if(diffKey.toLowerCase().indexOf(string) != -1)
                r[key] = value;
        }
    }
    return new Map(Object.entries(r));
}
```

With this function, you can do `search(string)` and it will return you the map that you were wanting originally.

Mainly you should writing a bunch of code without running anything.

Comment: for the first and second issue, it's here because people are looking for these "one run test" code, something related to the rule, on my side, i have it working differently.
on the third issue, it work without any issues at all, all diff are deleted if string is not found in any of the diff, and that mean the map need to be deleted then which doesn't work in my code, also i won't use this approach as i just don't like it